# How to transpose into the "same" column?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, transpose, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have a table like

```html
<table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-0lax">date</th>
    <th class="tg-0lax">organic</th>
    <th class="tg-0lax">referrer</th>
    <th class="tg-0lax">direct</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">01.01.2019</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">12345</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">123</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">23</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">25.01.2019</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">23456</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">234</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">34</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">03.03.2019</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">34567</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">345</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">56</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">15.04.2019</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">45678</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">456</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">78</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want to get the data into this view, where all data are placed into the same three columns, not dependently of whether points in the first column are repeated:

```html
<table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-0lax">type</th>
    <th class="tg-0lax">source</th>
    <th class="tg-0lax">date</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">organic</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">12345</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">01.01.2019</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">referrer</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">123</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">01.01.2019</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">direct</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">23</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">01.01.2019</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">organic</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">23456</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">25.01.2019</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">referrer</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">234</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">25.01.2019</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">direct</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">34</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">25.01.2019</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">organic</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">34567</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">03.03.2019</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">referrer</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">345</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">03.03.2019</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">direct</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">56</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">03.03.2019</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">organic</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">45678</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">15.04.2019</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">referrer</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">456</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">15.04.2019</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">direct</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">78</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">15.04.2019</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The "normal" transposing is pretty close to what I want, but even not exactly this, and I miss the point, how to pivot the data.

Another one example:

[image]

Got an error:
[image]

What I'm doing wrong? The formula is:

`=ARRAYFORMULA({"type","source","date";SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(IF(B2:D<>"","♠"&B1:D1&"♦"&B2:D&"♦"&A2:A, )),"♠")),"♦")})`
The line breaks are from the formula away - I've deleted them. Could the error cause be that my Google Spreadsheets used in Germany - formula language issue?

Comment: @player0 these data in both tables is a good matching example of what i have and what i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"type", "source", "date";
 SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(IF(B2:D<>"", 
 "♠"&B1:D1&"♦"&B2:D&"♦"&A2:A, )), "♠")), "♦")})
```

[image: 0]

Comment: yes, for german sheet use: `=ARRAYFORMULA({"type"\ "source"\ "date";
 SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(IF(B2:D<>""; 
 "♠"&B1:D1&"♦"&B2:D&"♦"&A2:A; )); "♠")); "♦")})`

Comment: still the same error. Was changed all Sheets language settings, everywhere, in the table settings and account settings - no luck.

Comment: Got It, don't know, how and why! Thank you! Could you educate me a bit please? What mean the ♠♦ characters?

Comment: sure. `♠♦` means nothing :) it's just a unique symbol (could be anything else ☺☻♥♀♂♪♫...) and the purpose is to use it in `SPLIT` as divisor. `=SPLIT("a♥b"; "♥")` will split `a` and `b` on `♥`